# Selenium check inside of class

Tags: java, python, selenium

For Selenium to check inside of a class (div) what can I do: Instance:

[Image of class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ5Rw.png)

I have that "seconds... 0"

I did:

```
....
driver.get('http://arithmetic.zetamac.com/game?key=96823302')
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('left')
```

Now I want:

```
while([TIME HERE] != 0):
.... run code
```

How can I get that value inside of the class out using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using,

```
XYZDocument.getElementsByClass("YourClassNameHere").get(0).text();
```

Here I used Jsoup to parse the HTML and produce a Document.